# iMac sees 16:9 monitor as 4:3

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors, imac

I've attached an LG Flatron W2246 monitor to my aluminium iMac, running 10.6.6. While I am able to use the monitor, when I open the display preferences pane, I am only offered resolutions with a 4:3 aspect ratio. The screen is 16:9.

I've tried using SwitchResX to add a new resolution for the screen, but it doesn't seem to like the 16:9 ratio I've set.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the monitor to work correctly using [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html), by adding a custom resolution based on 1920x1080 but with the checkbox "Use simplified settings (GFT)" ticked.

This sets the refresh rate to 60.107Hz that the screen looks brilliant; I have it linked to my iMac via the mini-display port, and it's almost as good as the iMac's screen.